# Activity, subActivity, Intent and IntentFilters in android?

Tags: android

i still have a problem to develop a convenient app to the user. because i am struggling using the activities, intent and intent filters. www.developer.android.com/reference not fit for me to understand these things. can you suggest me a fine example code or tutorial to understand how these things are getting worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a book is an option, i recommend you [Professional Android 2 Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527) by Reto Meier;
imho is the best and updated Android book available out there.